# GPUImageStillCamera Output Resolution Limited

Tags: ios, ipad, gpuimage

On an iPad 3 Retina with iOS 6.1, I initialize my still camera with:

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

I set up the camera with these filters:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-1x1.png"];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[sourcePicture processImage];

chromaKeyBlendFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[chromaKeyBlendFilter setColorToReplaceRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0];
[chromaKeyBlendFilter setThresholdSensitivity:0.37f];
filter = chromaKeyBlendFilter;

[stillCamera addTarget:filter];
[sourcePicture addTarget:filter];

[filter addTarget:videoPreviewView]; // 1024x768 view
[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

And when I capture the image I use:

```
[stillCamera capturePhotoAsPNGProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedPNG, NSError *error){
    self.currentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:processedPNG];
});
```

But the image I get back is screen-sized (Retina style) 2048x1536 instead of what I expect for the back camera as 2420x1936. I've also noticed that #imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation# only returns screen size as well and looking at the capture code in GPUImageStillCamera.m, it looks as though that is where the output originates.

I don't know why because I also have an option/button to use a non-GPUImage setup and I get back PNG images of 2420x1936.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any tips (because I *really* want 2420x1936).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I meant 2592x1936 for the iPad back camera full resolution (I crop the images for 8x10 size). As it turns out, I was trying to be too "smart".

When I tapped a button to capture an image, I used the following in a background thread to get the image which was saved to a property when it was asynchronously captured (in this case PNG files that get up to 8mb)

```
[stillCamera capturePhotoAsPNGProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedPNG, NSError *error)
self.currentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:processedPNG];
```

BUT, after dispatching that queue, I segued immediately to a preview view where I grabbed an image using

```
[filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp]
```

that was 2048x1516, enough to display on an iPad Retina for a preview. And then when that preview was dismissed, the self.currentImage was cropped and saved to a file (and Core Data metadata).

Where I got too "smart", when I noticed when the preview was showing, I was still getting logged KVO console messages from the camera. So, in viewWillDisappear I put in a "pause camera" and on reappear "resume camera". Apparently when the pause camera command is issued, it immediately stops processing and dumps what it has to my currentImage property and that was always a 2048x1516 image and not the full-res image if the preview could have waited a few more seconds.

IMHO, when the camera is paused, any background capture thread ought to continue until finished and THEN pause the camera. But I can work with this and I'm glad I found the issue.